# Do United Nations Security Council Resolutions emphasized phrases have a standard meaning?

Tags: united-nations

Reading some random United Nations Security Council Resolution documents (e.g. [1](http://www.un.org/webcast/pdfs/SRES2334-2016.pdf), [2](http://undocs.org/S/RES/2409(2018)), [3](http://undocs.org/S/RES/2408(2018))) I noticed that they contain some emphasized verbs (expressions) (italics) that seem to be from a predefined set:

- Reaffirming
- Condemning
- Expressing
- Stressing
- Calls upon
- Urges (..)
- Remaining deeply concerned

I am wondering if these are used in a meaningful way. E.g. *Expressing* might be a mere declaration while *Urges* might imply concrete actions in the future. Or they are just a nice and somewhat standard way of expressing resolution's points?

**Question:** Do United Nations Security Council Resolutions emphasized phrases have a standard meaning?

Comment: +1, although I had to look up the word 'syntagms' because I honestly thought it might have been a typo and was about to edit it. I'm curious if there was a particular reason you chose that word as opposed to 'phrases'?

Comment: @TexasRed - being a non-native English speaker is the main reason and my native language contains this word (as a neologism). Of course, "phrase" is more natural, so I have replaced the word. Thanks.

Comment: Glad I could help. Language is a funny thing, isn't it?

Comment: The *emphasized phrases* are not unique to the Security Council. They are used in resolutions by the General Assembly and the Economic and Social Council, as well.  *See* [Drafting Resolutions](https://www.un.org/en/model-united-nations/drafting-resolutions).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As the prior answer states, UN Security Council Resolutions come in two main parts (the third part is the name of the body): preambulary and operative clauses. In each case each "paragraph" starts with an italicized word. The individual meaning of these words is exactly what it seems, within a international context (e.g. authorizes would allow something to occur from individual member states).

What's actually important about these italicized words is the division between the preambulary and operative clauses as a whole. Whereas the preamble uses gerunds such as "Reaffirming" and "Recalling" and similar terms, the operative clauses, which are binding, use terms such as "Decides" "Appeals" and "Approves".

The preamble explains the context of the operative clauses, which are the binding clauses under International Law. As such, the *types* of italicized terms you see in the preamble are different from those in the operative clauses.

Comment: *Whereas the preamble uses gerunds ...* is not correct. They are often *participles*. See the quoted description in another answer: *a verb in the form of a present, past or perfect participle or an adjective*. *See also*, [What's the difference between a gerund and a participle?](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/66/346487).

Answer (score 5):

The usage context is international law.

[Editing of resolutions at the United Nations](http://www.un.org/en/ga/second/72/editingguidelines.pdf)

> **Structure of resolutions**
>
> **Paragraphs**
>
> Resolutions are essentially one long sentence. There are normally
>   three elements in a resolution: the name of the organ, the preamble
>   and the operative part.
>
> - **Preambular paragraphs** are not numbered. They serve to present the background to the action part of the resolution. Preambular
>     paragraphs must begin with a verb in the form of a present, past or
>     perfect participle or an adjective in italics. Examples of the types
>     of verbs and adjectives used in preambular paragraphs are provided in
>     the annex.

See the "Annex" for lists of "Common preambular verbs and adjectives" and "Common operative verbs".

---

The construction of words in law begins with the plain meaning of the words. In general, see [THE REHNQUIST COURT'S CANONS OF
STATUTORY CONSTRUCTION](http://www.ncsl.org/documents/lsss/2013pds/rehnquist_court_canons_citations.pdf). Only if there is ambiguity as to the meaning of a term should an ordinary or legal dictionary be consulted; along with legislative committee notes; etc.

The goal of construction is to determine the intent of the drafters of the document, not to insert meaning or purpose not found in the original document.

The linked document is relatively clear in language and purpose. One should not attempt to glean a legal meaning from ordinary words in the document which can be clearly defined.

If, however, the question is to the meaning of a term of art, examination of that term or combination of terms *does* require very careful consideration; for example, one legal term of art which can have different meaning depending on how interpreted is "notwithstanding" see [What happens when two conflicting laws both say “notwithstanding any other provision of law…”?](https://law.stackexchange.com/q/6898/14781).

Some of the words used in the cited document are not necessarily strictly legal terms, for example "Urges" and "Stress" are used to convey the "urging" of an action and to "stress" the point of the body which issued the resolution. "Calls upon" and "Remaining deeply concerned" are expressions used in various public settings, not only international law.

> Legal Definition of [reaffirm](https://www.merriam-webster.com/legal/reaffirm)
>
> 1 : to affirm again 2 : to agree to
>   the payment of (a dischargeable debt) with a creditor prior to the
>   discharge of debts in bankruptcy

> Legal Definition of [condemn](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/condemn#legalDictionary) 1 : to impose a penalty on; especially :
>   to sentence to death 2 : to adjudge unfit for use or consumption 3 :
>   to declare convertible to public use under the right of eminent domain
>   : take

> Legal Definition of [express](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/express#legalDictionary) : directly and distinctly stated or
>   expressed rather than implied or left to inference — compare
>   [implied](https://www.merriam-webster.com/legal/implied)

> Definition of [stress](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/stress) 1 : constraining force or influence: such as
>   a : a force exerted when one body or body part presses on, pulls on,
>   pushes against, or tends to compress or twist another body or body
>   part; especially : the intensity of this mutual force commonly
>   expressed in pounds per square inch b : the deformation caused in a
>   body by such a force c : a physical, chemical, or emotional factor
>   that causes bodily or mental tension and may be a factor in disease
>   causation d : a state resulting from a stress; especially : one of
>   bodily or mental tension resulting from factors that tend to alter an
>   existent equilibrium job-related stress e : strain, pressure 2
>   : emphasis, weight 3 archaic : intense effort or
>   exertion 4 : intensity of utterance given to a speech sound, syllable,
>   or word producing relative loudness 5 a : relative force or prominence
>   of sound in verse b : a syllable having relative force or prominence 6
>   : accent 5a

> [call upon](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/call%20on)
>
> 1 : [require](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/require), [oblige](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/oblige) 2 : to make a demand on : depend on

> Definition of [urge](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/urge)
>
> urged; urging 
>   transitive verb
>
> 1 : to present,
>   advocate, or demand earnestly or pressingly 2 : to undertake
>   the accomplishment of with energy, swiftness, or enthusiasm 3 a : solicit, entreat b : to serve as
>   a motive or reason for 4 : to force or impel
>   in an indicated direction or into motion or greater speed 5 : [stimulate](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/stimulate), [provoke](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/provoke)
>
> verb : to declare,
>   advance, or press earnestly a statement, argument, charge, or claim

> Definition of [concerned](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/concerned) 1 a : [anxious](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/anxious), [worried](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/worried) b :
>   [interested](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/interested)  2 a : interestedly engaged b : culpably involved

---

If the question is when to use which verb or term, that is an art.